# jQuery slideToggle on iPhone leaving line artifacts

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile-safari

I'm having a bit of an issue with the slideToggle on the iPhone.

After a ul is expanded there are some line artifacts left on the screen. (Right click on the image > view image to view it at full size)

[image]

The weird part here is that when I zoom in very slightly the lines disappear. Than when I zoom out again the lines are still gone.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("a").click(function () {
      var a = jQuery(this);          
      a.siblings("ul").slideToggle("slow");
      var url = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
      if (url != undefined && url.length > 0) return true;
      return false;
    });
  }); 
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  li
  {
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
  }

  ul
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;

    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #nav
  {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    border: none;  
    background-color: #fff;  
  }

  #nav ul
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #nav ul ul
  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #nav ul li
  {
    padding-bottom: 7px;  
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #nav ul li.last
  {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  #nav ul li > a
  {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #05548D;
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  #nav ul ul li > a
  {
    background: #1872BE;      
  }
</style>

<div id="nav">
  <ul>    
    <li><a href="">News &gt;</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/Latest-News.aspx">Latest News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/Upcoming-events.aspx">Upcoming events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/Media-releases.aspx">Media releases</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/International-updates.aspx">International updates</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/eNewsletter.aspx">eNewsletter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="Mobile-Home/News/Register-for-updates.aspx">Register for updates</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Boy, that's subtle. Would this really make a difference in mobile safari to an end user? Seems like it could be a lot of hassle for something that really isn't an issue.

Comment: The problem is the client is complaining about it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this is a while ago, so I guess you may have already solved this, but I was having the same problem and hunted aroudn for a solution, and in the end came up with this, so I thought I would share the solution in case you were still looking.

By resetting the background color at the end of the animation this prevents these artifacts building up.

`var a = jQuery(this);
    var callback = function(){
        $('#ul').css({'background':'#FFF'});
    }
    a.siblings("ul").slideToggle("slow",callback);`

Hope that helps

Patch